# Function(a1) how to get a1 inside my function (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, function

I need to create a function that outputs a result based on whether a cell is merged or not.

To do that I need to check if each cell from a1...aN is merged or not. But I haven't found a way to get the cell "a1" when I call function(a1). All I can get is the value of the cell and not the cell itself.

Is there a way to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. A function must return something. What do you expect the output to be? Also, post the code yu've tried and where are you stuck

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! I am stuck at the first step. 

I declare my function

Function MergedDescription(cell As Range) 

and I want to check if cell is merged. I've found the method(?) I need to use, however I can't check for the cell i am passing as parameter. If I do a return 

MergedDescription = cell

I get the value that's in the cell.

I hope this clears it up. 

Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: `cell` is the cell passed to the function. `MergedDescription = cell` will return the cell value since that's the default property.

Comment: @Rory yes that's what I figured. The question is how do I get the cell itself e.g. a1? Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: You refer to it with the parameter (range object) `cell` e.g. `If cell.MergeCells Then MergedDescription = True`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 yes that's it. Thank you. I don't know how to accept the answer..